# Pull an array from wikipedia html table rows using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I saw @wesbos get an array from a wiki page [JavaScript Array Cardio Practice](https://youtu.be/HB1ZC7czKRs?t=11m44s)

Thought I'd try it myself and get some interesting arrays to practice with. However a lot of the wiki pages have the info in tables, I've been trying to get an array from [List of NME number-one singles of the 1960s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NME_number-one_singles_of_the_1960s)

Here I've selected the right table and picked out the tr

```
    const tables = document.querySelectorAll('.wikitable');
    const table = tables[1];
    const tr = table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
```

I need the inner text from the td in each row, by selecting a single tr and using map() I can get an array

```
    const theTD = Array.from(tr[67].querySelectorAll('td'));
    const theText = theTD.map(item => item.innerText);
    console.log(theText);
```

How can I iterate through the whole table and get a multidimensional array, I've been trying with forEach but I just get back undefined
Thanks
Andrew

Comment: `array.forEach` does not return anything. Also, you are on the right track. `.map(item => item.innerText)` is for data for 1 row. You have to do same for `tr`s in 1 table

Comment: _Thought I'd try it myself and get some interesting arrays to practice with._ - So what did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already figured out some of the portion, so after

```
const tables = document.querySelectorAll('.wikitable');
const table = tables[1];
const tr = table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
```

you can do this

```
var result = Array.from(tr).map((x) => { 
  var theTD = x.querySelectorAll('td');  
  var theText = Array.from(theTD).map(item => item.innerText); 
  return theText; 
});
```

Here, I have added one map, over your one. Like columns, you can iterate on rows as well with the help of map.

Comment: Thanks Vipin thats' a great answer

Comment: Do you know how I could name the index keys so now it's 0: "example-artist" 1: "example-song" 2: "example-date" 3: "example-weeks"  I would like to name those keys like this  artist: "example-artist", song"example-song" etc...

Comment: Also is there any way to export that array to use in a project offline? Thanks for your help

Comment: yes, but i'm not in front of my computer. Will revert back once available. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.

```js
const tables = [...document.querySelectorAll('.wikitable')]

console.log(
  tables.map(table => ({ 
    id: table.id,
    "class": table.className,
    data: (function() {
      
      // get the data from each cell and header
      const rows = [...table.querySelectorAll('tr')]
        .map(row => 
          [...row.querySelectorAll('th, td')]
            .map(x => x.textContent)
        )
      // extract the headers
      const headers = rows.shift()
      
      // return objects with the headers as keys
      return {
        json: rows.map(row => row.reduce((acc, x, i) => ({ 
          ...acc,
          [headers[i]]: x
        }), {})),
        multidimensional: [
          headers,
          ...rows
        ]
      }

    })()
  }))
)
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
<table id="test" class="wikitable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>one</th>
      <th>two</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this wiki page, following script will work;

```
let table = document.querySelectorAll('.wikitable')[1];
let alltds = table.querySelectorAll('.vcard .fn a');
for(i=0;i<alltds.length;i++) { 
   console.log(alltds[i].innerHTML) ; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this :-

```
const tables = document.querySelectorAll('.wikitable');
const table = tables[1];
const tr = table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');

var output = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++){
     const theTD = Array.from(tr[i].querySelectorAll('td'));
     const theText = theTD.map(item => item.innerText);
     if(theText.length > 0 ){
        output.push(theText);
     }
}
```